# Iterate through elements of a table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

I am trying to get all `td`s from a particular row.

Here is the code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var widthArray = new Array();
  var i=0;
  $('#firstRow > td').each(function () {
    var tdclass = $('td').attr('class');
    console.log(tdclass);
    widthArray.push(tdclass);
    i=i+1;
  });
});
```

But it stops at the first `td` instead of iterating.

**UPDATE:** the `i` variable is for a different function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#firstRow > td')
```

This is correct. The above snippet selects all the `td`s which are inside `#firstRow` element.

The problem is in the loop.

```
var tdclass = $('td').attr('class');
```

Here you're ignoring the selected `td` on which you're looping over, and selects all the `td`s present in the page; that's what the `$('td')` function does.

When you use jQuery, the loop callback receives the element both as parameter, both as context (`this`); [$.fn.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) for reference.

So to fix your problem:

```
$('#firstRow > td').each(function (index, element) {
    var tdclass = $(element).attr('class');
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank's...that saved the day,  I will accept the answer when SO lets me do so in about 10 min.

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration you get the class of the first `<td>` element in the set of `$('td')`. You can change your construction to more elegant:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var widthArray = $("#firstRow > td").map(function() {
            return this.className;
        }).get(),
        i = widthArray.length;

    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks but @Bruno's answer did it...Thanks anyway